# How to replace a specified number of characters AFTER a string

Tags: replace, vbscript

Is there a way I can find `USER.A` and replace only the 6 characters after it?

Currently I am using:

```
Replace(strText, Left("USER.A", 12), "USER.A170510")
```

The result is `USER.A170510170509` (the previous days date).

I need it to just be `USER.A170510`, without eliminating the rest of the code before or after. I tried using `Left()` and `Right()` in the old and/or new text fields and that did not seem to work.

The date will always need to change to the current date after USER.A, but the script may not run every day, so I can't just find the previous days date and replace that.

Here is the full script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\users\userID\desktop\file.ext", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, Left("USER.A", 12), "USER.A170510")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\users\userID\desktop\file.ext", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText

objFile.Close
```

The date will eventually be a formula but I haven't worked on that piece yet. Right now I just need the characters to replace after a specific starting text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of `strNewText = Replace(strText, Left("USER.A", 12), "USER.A170510")`

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx.Pattern = "USER\.A[0-9]{6}"

strNewText =  objRegEx.Replace(strText, "USER.A170510")
```

Comment: I received the error:
"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property"
Assignment 'objRegEx.Replace'
Code: 800A01C2

This is what I have on that line:
strNewText =  objRegEx.Replace(strText, "USER.A", "USER.A" + tdate)

I know for a fact that tdate works, because it works when I have it set as:
Replace(strText, "USER.A" + pdate, "USER.A" + tdate)

pdate is the previous date, and tdate is todays date
But, this is a workaround.
Do I have something wrong on that line?

Comment: Try `objRegEx.Pattern = "USER\.A[0-9]{6}"`

Comment: same error 800A01C2. I tried placing SET in front of the strNewText, but that did not work, per http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_800A01C2.htm. It does seem to want something at the beginning of that line, because its referencing Char 1 in that error.

Comment: @Excel_Wiz Please pay attention to the error message and the answer. The `objRegEx.Replace()` method expects **TWO** arguments. You're trying to call it with **THREE** arguments. And you MUST NOT use the `Set` keyword there.

Comment: My Bad, thank you!
I did have to add objRegEx.Pattern = "USER\.A[0-9]{6}" for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\users\userID\desktop\file.ext", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strFind = "USER.A"
intPos = inStr(1,strText,strFind,1)
If intPos>0 then
    strReplaceText = Mid(strText,intPos ,12)
    strNewText = Replace(strText, strReplaceText , "USER.A170510")
End If
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\users\userID\desktop\file.ext", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText

objFile.Close
```